# Turning off GPS in background

Tags: ios5, gps, core-location, background-process

I am using CoreLocation to determine user's location to calculate the distance and show the route on the map. To minimize battery usage I am turning off GPS after getting location and turning it on again after 1 minute. When the application is active everything works fine, but after sending it to background and turning off GPS, the app seems to be inactive at all, it doesn't output anything (using `NSLog()`). I have added directive to `info.plist` file to allow the application to run in background. When I don't turn off the GPS in background the app works as well as in foreground.

So my question is the following: does GPS always need to be turned on in background to prevent the application to be suspended or there is another workaround (because the turned GPS drains the battery)?

P.S. I am new to iOS and mobile development at all, so maybe there are some tips that I have to know.

Comment: if GPS is off in background there are no events triggering actions. Did you set up a timer, and looked if your app is active?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have a timer and it doesn't work when GPS is off in background. But it works while the GPS is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Apple does not support long running background task in general.
This does only work for specific tasks:

audio, 
location, 
voip,
newsstand-content,
external-accessory,
bluetooth-central and
bluetooth-peripheral

When you do not use any of that, your app could be suspended.
In your case ypu have specified location, but disabled the location update. Then for apple there is no reason to keep your app in background mode.

Comment: is there any workaround for this situation besides having GPS always turned on in background?

Comment: or maybe there is some time interval before suspending, let's say 2 minutes, and during that time I can turn off GPS without being suspended and turn on again.

Comment: yes in that docu is stater that you can request more time for save  suspend.